# why is CodeContracts static checker suggesting that I Contract.Assume(a) right after I Contract.Ensure(a)?

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract-class, code-contracts, post-conditions

Basically, I have a virtual method to propagate certain mandatory postconditions to subclasses. Here's a simplified version and the strange warnings the static checker generates (edit - my example was incomplete. It's right now):

```
public abstract class InitializerClass
{
    protected bool _initialized

    public bool IsInitialized
    {
        get { return _initialized; }
    }

    public virtual void Initialize()
    {
        //Warning CodeContracts: Missing precondition in an externally visible
        //method. Consider adding Contract.Requires(this.IsInitialized); for
        //parameter validation
        Contract.Ensures(IsInitialized);
    }
}
```

this is the other class:

```
public abstract class OrderingClass
{
    protected bool _ordered

    public bool IsOrdered
    {
        get { return _ordered; }
    }

    public override void Initialize()
    {
        //Message CodeContracts: Suggested assume: Contract.Assume(this.IsOrdered);
        Contract.Ensures(IsOrdered);
    }
}
```

in fact, both warnings are pointing to the closing curly brace of the methods, in the lines just bellow the Contract.Ensure calls. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: I clearly can't add `Contract.Requires(IsInitialized)` to `InitializerClass.Initialize`, because ensuring `IsInitialized` is set to true as a post-condition is the point of the contract. Those things are mutually exclusive. Same thing with the `OrderingClass.Initialize` override. Am I missing something or is the static checker just really confused?

Comment: There actually is code setting _initialized to true in the method, right? Better add it to be clear.

Comment: No such warning is produced using CodeContracts version 1.7.11202.10 static checking, with the warning level and options cranked up, whichever way I try to fix the code (in addition to Henk's comment: missing semicolumns, override without base class).

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because Code Contracts cannot verify that calling `Initialize()` will result in `IsInitialized` returning true. This is because there is no code in the body of `Initialize()` that sets the value of `IsInitialized` to `true`, hence the analyzer is warning you that the code is assuming `IsInitialized` is `true` on entry to `Initialize()`, and that you should make this precondition explicit.

There are two ways to eliminate the warning.

First, add the suggested pre-condition:

```
public virtual void Initialize()
{
    Contract.Requires(IsInitialized);
    Contract.Ensures(IsInitialized);
}
```

Second, set the value of `IsInitialized` to `true`:

```
public virtual void Initialize()
{
    IsInitialized = true;
    Contract.Ensures(IsInitialized);
}
```

You will need to add a private setter to `IsInitialized` in order for the above code to work.

```
public bool IsInitialized
{
    get { return _initialized; }
    private set { __initialized = value; }
}
```

Simply setting `_initialized = true` in `Initialize()` probably won't allow Code Contracts to verify the post-condition, hence adding the private setter. However, having said that adding the following contract to `IsInitialized` may negate the need to add the property setter:

```
public bool IsInitialized
{
    get
    {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<bool>() ^ !_initialized);
        return _initialized; 
    }
}
```

You are getting the warning in`OrderingClass` for the exact same reason. Code Contracts suggests `Contract.Assume()` because you cannot use `Contract.Requires()` in overrides.